# ConTeXt: How to style interactive elements individually rather than globally

Tags: context, urls, links, interaction

I want two have two links, one bold and one normal.

As a MWE:

```
\setupinteraction[state=start,style=normal]
\starttext

{\bf\goto{Link 1}[url(http://www.example.com)]}

\goto{Link 2}[url(http://www.example2.com)]

\stoptext
```

These two links have the same style (neither are bold). If I omit the `style=normal`, then they still have the same style (both are bold). Is there no way to style links individually?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can define a new *interaction* and style it differently. For example:

```
\setupinteraction[state=start,style=normal]
\defineinteraction[bold][state=start,style=bold]
\starttext

{\setinteraction[bold] \goto{Link 1}[url(http://www.example.com)]}

\goto{Link 2}[url(http://www.example2.com)]

\stoptext
```

If you want the interaction to follow the style of the surrounding style, simply unset `style`. For example,

```
\setupinteraction[state=start,style=]
\starttext

{\bf \goto{Link 1}[url(http://www.example.com)]}

\goto{Link 2}[url(http://www.example2.com)]

\stoptext
```

Comment: Thanks for your help. I'm very new to ConTeXt and I keep forgetting to try basic stuff like this.

Comment: Don't worry. ConTeXt has a very consistent user interface. It takes some time to get used to, but once it _clicks_, you'll just be able to guess the solutions.

Answer (score 2):

If I change the position of the \bf directive, I seem to get your desired result:

```
\setupinteraction[state=start,style=normal]
\starttext

{\goto{\bf Link 1}[url(http://www.example.com)]}

\goto{Link 2}[url(http://www.example2.com)]

\stoptext
```

However, I am uncertain if there might be side effects to this.